# MS Excel Pivot Table - Error when removing values from filter

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, dimension

I face the following problem on MS Excel (both on 2010 and 2013, I think that this does not have to do with Officer version) :

I have a Pivot Table connecting to an Analysis Services Cube.

I drug 2 Dimensions in the Filter field, and one Measure in the Worksheet.
Then I get the calculation formula for the measure, using Options -> OLAP Tools -> Convert to formulas, and copy that to another cell.
So, let's say that the original Measure lies on A10 and the calculated on B10.

The problem happens with the first of my two dimensions.
When I select "All" members from this dimension everything is fine, but when I remove a member (any member) , the original Measure (A10) is ok, but mine on B10 gets an error ('N/A').

This does not happen when making changes to the selection of the second dimension filter though.

Any ideas on this one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In case someone has the same problem, have in mind that problem turned out to be that when selecting (lots of) specific dimension members instead "All", the query that was create by excel was longer than the maximum allowed length.

This error may happen when constructing queries using dimensions that have lots of members.

Comment: There is no "correct" solution. 
One custom solution is to revert the query, so that selected members are excluded from selection, instead of including.
That way users do not select too many dimension members in case they want to select all but a few of them.

The actual problem is the maximum length of OLAP query that Excel executes on SSAS, which is exceeded when too many dimension members are selected.